# How to get all the child nodes of an xml data based on parent node in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Is there any way that I can retrieve all the child nodes along with sub child nodes if I just provide the Parent node of an xml data. The output should not hold the Parent tag.

I tried with below query but it is also returning the parent tag in the output.

Input XML Data

```xml
<GrandGrandParent>
    <GrandParent>
        <Parent1>
            <Child1>ABC</Child1>
            <Child2>DEF</Child2>
        </Parent1>
        <Parent2>
            <Child1>GHI</Child1>
            <Child2>JKL</Child2>
            <Child3>
                <Child1>MNO</Child1>
                <Child2>PQR</Child2>
            </Child3>
        </Parent2>
    </GrandParent>
</GrandGrandParent>
```

Expected Output

```xml
        <Parent1>
            <Child1>ABC</Child1>
            <Child2>DEF</Child2>
        </Parent1>
        <Parent2>
            <Child1>GHI</Child1>
            <Child2>JKL</Child2>
            <Child3>
                <Child1>MNO</Child1>
                <Child2>PQR</Child2>
            </Child3>
        </Parent2>
```

Actual Output

```xml
<GrandParent>
        <Parent1>
            <Child1>ABC</Child1>
            <Child2>DEF</Child2>
        </Parent1>
        <Parent2>
            <Child1>GHI</Child1>
            <Child2>JKL</Child2>
            <Child3>
                <Child1>MNO</Child1>
                <Child2>PQR</Child2>
            </Child3>
        </Parent2>
    </GrandParent>
```

Query I have used

```sql
select extract(xmltype('<GrandGrandParent>
    <GrandParent>
        <Parent1>
            <Child1>ABC</Child1>
            <Child2>DEF</Child2>
        </Parent1>
        <Parent2>
            <Child1>GHI</Child1>
            <Child2>JKL</Child2>
            <Child3>
                <Child1>MNO</Child1>
                <Child2>PQR</Child2>
            </Child3>
        </Parent2>
    </GrandParent> 
</GrandGrandParent>'),'//GrandParent')  xml from  dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXTRACT` is deprecated. Use `XMLQUERY` (or `XMLTABLE`):

```sql
SELECT XMLQUERY(
         '//GrandParent/*'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(value)
         RETURNING CONTENT
       ).getClobVal() AS child_nodes
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (value CLOB);

INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES (
  '<GrandGrandParent>
    <GrandParent>
        <Parent1>
            <Child1>ABC</Child1>
            <Child2>DEF</Child2>
        </Parent1>
        <Parent2>
            <Child1>GHI</Child1>
            <Child2>JKL</Child2>
            <Child3>
                <Child1>MNO</Child1>
                <Child2>PQR</Child2>
            </Child3>
        </Parent2>
    </GrandParent>
</GrandGrandParent>'
);
```

```
1 rows affected
```

Outputs:

| CHILD_NODES |
| --- |
| <Parent1><Child1>ABC</Child1><Child2>DEF</Child2></Parent1><Parent2><Child1>GHI</Child1><Child2>JKL</Child2><Child3><Child1>MNO</Child1><Child2>PQR</Child2></Child3></Parent2> |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6trj2L2p)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select extract(xmltype('<GrandGrandParent>
    <GrandParent>
        <Parent1>
            <Child1>ABC</Child1>
            <Child2>DEF</Child2>
        </Parent1>
        <Parent2>
            <Child1>GHI</Child1>
            <Child2>JKL</Child2>
            <Child3>
                <Child1>MNO</Child1>
                <Child2>PQR</Child2>
            </Child3>
        </Parent2>
    </GrandParent> 
</GrandGrandParent>'),'/GrandGrandParent/GrandParent/*')  xml from  dual
```